# While ing vs with ing vs in ing vs ing

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

1. > Drivers who talk on their phone **while driving** pose a significant risk to pedestrians and other motorists and should therefore be punished.
2. > Drivers who talk on their phone **with driving** pose a significant risk to pedestrians and other motorists and should therefore be punished.
3. > Drivers who talk on their phone **in driving** pose a significant risk to pedestrians and other motorists and should therefore be punished.
4. > Drivers who talk on their phone **driving** pose a significant risk to pedestrians and other motorists and should therefore be punished.

I want to know how they are different in meaning semantically, or if needed logically.
And if there is something which does not make sense, please explain it why it does if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, 'driving' is the state the driver is in, as such the correct word is 'while'.

'with' and 'in' are incorrect because they both expect a noun.
Not using any word at all is incorrect because you have to describe the relation between the driver and the word 'driving', not using anything would cause most readers to try to clump together 'phone' and 'driving' into a single phrase 'phone driving' which doesn't make sense.

Incidentally, you can omit the 'while driving' since you've already identified the subject as 'drivers' hence it's clear by context that you're talking about people who are driving:

> Drivers who talk on their phone pose a significant risk to pedestrians and other motorists and should therefore be punished.

However 'motorists' may be a more appropriate word choice.

Edit: To address Andrew's comment, in this case 'driving' is referring to the verb 'to drive' rather than acting as a noun, so you can't use 'with'. 'while' needs to be used as you are talking about two things happening simultaneously, such that talking on the phone is happening at the same time as (*while*) the person is driving.

Comment: Actually "driving" is a noun when used as a *gerund*, e.g.  "With cooking, it's fine if everyone tries and fails -- but **with driving**, it's better if they get some training first."  To make the answer more complete I think you could consider whether it is related to this specific verb ("to drive") or the verb tense used in this sentence ("driving"), and explain more about why "while" is appropriate here.

Comment: Actually, in "while driving..." *driving* is a present participle that can be related to the progressive tense that is implicit in that reduced clause, as "while driving" is short for "while **they are** driving".

Comment: I don't understand why with cannot be used only by the reason that with needs a noun because, as far as I know, with means 'together'. That is to say, can  with decribe a simultaneous situation like while?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why in is not appropriate in the sentence because I have seen quite a few sentences where 'in Ving' is used.

Comment: Maybe I got to know why in is not correct. The reason is that the subject could be thought of as drivers who talk on the phone while another driver next to them is driving in the sentence.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois 'with' cannot describe a simultaneous situation like this, because 'with' means you are acting together with someone else, so even if the person next to you was the one driving you'd have to say 'Passengers who talk on their phones with drivers' or 'with someone driving', not just 'with driving'. 'in' is a preposition and cannot be used in this way, it's not that you can be misunderstood but rather that it's simply the wrong word.

Comment: @otah007 As for with, I got it 100%. I am so sorry to reapeat asking you for a reasonble answer, and I know how difficult it is to help foreigners to understand an English question which, for native speakers, looks nothing to discuss because it is so obvious, but nevertheless would you please explain why in does not make sense in the sentence?

Comment: Then, what if rephrased like this "In driving, drivers who talk on their phone pose a significant risk to pedestrians and other motorists and should therefore be punished."

Comment: The point is that you do not want to modify "drivers," who by necessity are driving in order to be drivers. Rather you want to link temporally talking and driving. The meaning is "People who talk on their phone and drive a motor vehicle **at the same time** pose a danger to others and so deserve punishment." Le mot juste, c'est "while."